# How to while list aws load balancer URL in mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, aws-application-load-balancer, atlas

I want to white list the load balancer URL in the mongodb network access but it is asking for CIDR which i don't have public CIDR atleast

Answer (score 0):

At the moment based off the [Add IP Access List Entries documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#add-ip-access-list-entries), the Network Access List only accepts  IP address, CIDR block, or AWS Security Group ID.